# Installing Windows 3.11 For Workgroups on ESXi Server

Tags: windows, vmware-esx, vmware-esxi

Hello I was able to install MS-DOS 6.0 on the ESXi server and was able to install 3.11 windows, but when I try to start windows for the first time the mouse and keyboard dont work. I can see the cursor blinking on the password prompt so it doesnt look like it froze but I cant do anything. Any  thoughts ? Thanks

Comment: +1 for stupidity!  Why ever would you do that?  I salute your foolishness!

Comment: Same reason some people like to get their system to dual boot 20 different operating systems :)

Comment: Not Stupidity, we have a need to Windows 3.11 for workgroups, its a MS supported OS, and still hasnt reach EOL.

Comment: geoffc: Having a Windows 1.03 virtual machine, I hereby punch you in the face.

Comment: @user8210 You may indeed have a need for it, but I can assure you that it is not a Microsoft Supported OS.  Support has long since expired...  And if you have a legitimate need for Windows 3.11, you're probably (doing whatever it is that you're doing) wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 3.1x is supported under ESX 4.0

http://pubs.vmware.com/guestnotes/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=guestnotes&file=guestos_doswin.html

Also see the known issues section

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I need it on ESXi which is under 3.5 structure.

Comment: Just because you need it doesn't make it possible.  It's possible the virtual hardware support isn't present in 3.5 to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a WFW 3.11 VM I had created under Vmware workstation 4.x on an ESX 3.5i server and it worked for me.  I have no idea why it wouldn't be working for you.  Perhaps the virtual hardware that is selected for a new VM is different then what I got from the imported VM.

You might want to try creating a VM in an older version Vmware and then importing it.

Comment: I`m going to try that right now. I have VMworkstation 6.5 where it works fine, I did import it from there but it was created with 5 settings let me try.

Comment: Nope same thing, mouse and keyboard are not working.... Can you run thru your settings please? I created in VMware workstation 6.5 with 4 settings, selected windows 3.1 as the OS and all the other defaults. Then used VMware Vcenter standalone converter and took all the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ESX only emulates USB keyboards and mice? just an idea - not sure but it would explain it.

Comment: Yeah, that would be my first theory as well.  No USB support there.

Comment: I thought of it, but it looks like its PS/2 as in windows XP on that same box in device manager it shows PS/2

Comment: Nope, ESX emulates PS/2 mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the MS-DOS prompt, switch to the \windows folder and run SETUP. Check to see if the installtion options (particularly the keyboard) match your real-life setup.

(Man this is bringing back memories of the old days)

Comment: Did that some thing.

Answer (score -1):

Just stay in MSDOS and run DoomSweeper and you will be fine. You don't need any Windows.